# Create a new pdf file with password using c++

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt4

I want to create a pdf file with password using Qt 4.3.2 , I created a pdf file successfully, but I need to create a password to that file and I am stuck here. Please help me.

My code is

```
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setHtml("<h1>hello, I'm an head</h1>");
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFileName("E:\\pdf file\\file.pdf");
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
doc.print(&printer);
```

Here I am creating a pdf file, now I want to create a password to that file
any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: As pointed out in [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/30725/qprinter-write-password-protected-pdf), Qt doesn't support it. You need a third party library for it (use your favorite search engine).